# Xcode workspace with Unity3D as a sub-project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Let's say we're developing a 2D game with Cocos2d-iPhone and UIKit and CoreAnimation. But we're also considering leveraging the 3D capabilities of Unity 3D.

Is it possible that we add the Unity3D-generated Xcode project as a sub-project into the workspace and expose the 3D UI element as some kind of UIView subclass so that the native UIKit and CoreAnimation code could use them without the need to mess up with their underlying Unity3D implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The guys from [Blurst](http://technology.blurst.com/a-cocoa-based-frontend-for-unity-iphone-applications/) have made some games using Cocoa as frontend and Unity to 3D stuffs. Take a look on links below, there are very good informations on them:

- [A Cocoa-Based Frontend For Unity iPhone Applications](http://technology.blurst.com/a-cocoa-based-frontend-for-unity-iphone-applications/)
- [Building a iOS Unity + UIView / UIViewController / Interface Builder
  App](http://alexanderwong.me/post/29949258838/building-a-ios-unity-uiview-uiviewcontroller)
- [An Experiment with iPhone Native UI and Unity 3 Pro](http://clevermartian.com/blog/?p=59)
- [Unity Iphone App Embebed in objectiveC app](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/50953-Unity-Iphone-App-Embebed-in-objectiveC-app)