# Using Unity3D in one of the iOS App's views

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have an iOS app built natively using Cocoa. Now, I want to add a Unity3D simulation to it. Is it possible to invoke Unity simulation/screen on a button click on a native screen? Or do I have write my entire native iOS app as a plugin to the Unity screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is "Is it possible?" the answer is "Yes". As to the how:

http://www.markuszancolo.at/2014/05/integrating-unity-into-a-native-ios-app

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to post this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation to do so (yet).

I contributed extensively to this thread here:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/191971-Unity-AppController-subclassing

I have been able to successfully integrate Unity views within a native iOS project, whether it be programatically, via a XIB, or even via a StoryBoard.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

The guys from [Blurst](http://technology.blurst.com/a-cocoa-based-frontend-for-unity-iphone-applications/) have made some games using Cocoa as frontend and Unity to 3D stuffs. Take a look on links below, there are very good informations on them:

- [A Cocoa-Based Frontend For Unity iPhone Applications](http://technology.blurst.com/a-cocoa-based-frontend-for-unity-iphone-applications/)
- [Building a iOS Unity + UIView / UIViewController / Interface Builder
  App](http://alexanderwong.me/post/29949258838/building-a-ios-unity-uiview-uiviewcontroller)
- [An Experiment with iPhone Native UI and Unity 3 Pro](http://clevermartian.com/blog/?p=59)
- [Unity Iphone App Embebed in objectiveC app](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/50953-Unity-Iphone-App-Embebed-in-objectiveC-app)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175771/2496464