# Unity IOS integration

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

For a project I need to integrate Unity3d in an existing app I know Unity acts as a UIApplicationDelegate. I found an interesting article about this topic but it is not really clear to me how I can resolve my problems this way. Is it possible restart the delegation process from a ViewController? So when I switch to a viewController from my delegate and I want to navigate back then initialize the UIApplicationDelegate again?

Article I found:
http://alexanderwong.me/post/29949258838/building-a-ios-unity-uiview-uiviewcontroller

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the links from this question are intersting for you: [Using Unity3D in one of the iOS App's views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507133/using-unity3d-in-one-of-the-ios-apps-views)

Comment: What they do is adding some subviews to Unity like buttons. Or how to send messages to Unity and back from Unity to Objective C. What I want to try is create my own delegate like Alexander Wong did is his article. This would be my default ViewController from where I navigate  to my other viewcontrollers. When a user navigates back to the default viewcontroller it would be nice that unity coud be started from there on a button click.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Unity to build a "standard" Unity iOS application, then integrating your existing code into that?

When you build for iOS from Unity, Unity will automatically stick a hook in your Application Delegate, in the following method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

You can do other stuff in there, but down the bottom you should see the important line:

```
[self startUnity:application];
```

So what you can do is just take that line out of the didFinishLaunching method and put it ... wherever you want. You'll also want to keep a reference to the UIWindow* Unity draws to in your application delegate, so you can switch in and out of it as you please.

So, I'm not completely clear about exactly the things you want to do, but I definitely recommend as a first step you start with an integrated Unity build and work from there, or at least use it as a map if you want to roll your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while, but better late then never ;)

You can not "restart" the delegation stuff. The UnityAppController is an AppDelegate, not a ViewController.
But you can decide when unity is started the first time. After that, unity is running and you have to either use the applicationDidEnterBackground call in the UnityAppController (for pre Unity 5) or just call setPause:true (using Unity 5) which stops the unity render loop. Just dont forget to reactivate it once you navigate back to the UnityViewController.

For the "how to start unity when u want to": Either subclass UnityAppController and override startUnity:(UIApplication*) application with an empty implementation. Then you call [super startUnity..] once you want to activate it.

The other way is not to subclass but create your own UnityAppController object and call all the methods (applicationDidFinsishLaunching etc.). Then you just wait with the initialization till you need unity for the first time. But i would recommend the first option.

You can also look here for a more detailed Description how i did it: http://www.markuszancolo.at/2014/05/integrating-unity-into-a-native-ios-app