# Activating Unity on iOS Button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have an iOS app, with diffrent views, and I would like to open a Unity project on click of a button. This would be an augmented reality part of the App, which thus uses the qualcomm plugin for Unity. 
I followed the guide http://alexanderwong.me/post/29949258838/building-a-ios-unity-uiview-uiviewcontroller as much as possible, but have a few problems

1. Ideally, I would like to load Unity on the touch of the button, not on AppStart, I have the method that get calls when the button is touched, but honestly have no idea what should go there  `UnityPause: NO` ??
2. If not possible to load Unity at Button click, then at it should be loaded on *application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*, and, as in the guide, I call the AppController window from AppDelegate ..

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:                     (NSDictionary*)launchOptions
   {
   //unity
   BOOL returnBOOL;
   if (_unityController == nil) {
       _unityController = [[AppController alloc] init];
   }
   returnBOOL = [_unityController application:application     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

   //other app-loading things here...
   CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
   self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
   NSLog(@"Will start loading Unity window");

   // unity, set window
   window = [_unityController window];  //App crashes here

   // navigation controller
   [window addSubview:navigationController.view];


   self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
   self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;

   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   //more loading things....

   return returnBOOL;
   }
   ```

and then on AppController.mm I have:

```
- (UIWindow *)window
{
return _window; 
}
```

This throws me a compiler error "Use of undeclared identifier _window", ok, I get this is wrong, he doesn't know where _window comes from.. but what I dont know, is where it *should* come from.. and I don't really know how to fix this.

And lastly, for performance reasons, if I had to load Unity only at button click, what should get called there? (Unity takes very long to load, I'm not really sure if it's better to load it at AppStart, or at Button Click, (won't it look wierd if you click the button, and it takes long to open the camera?).. any help would be apreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: and I swear I have already read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596772/unity-ios-integration, but I didn't really understand it :(

Comment: The article mentioned that You need to start unity at appstart and then can pause it, to switch back to the objective C. You can't load unity at your will. I don't know if he's correct about that.

Comment: I do think it would be too hard to load it after the app has finished loading, and it would be easier to do it all in the beginning, but I still have the window problem there.. any ideas? :)

Comment: @Cutetare - Hello, there. Did you manage to implement it on the button click? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @shivamkaushik I dont have the project anymore, but I thiiiiiiiink I ended up hacking it, loading it normally in the beginning,and then putting a screen on the top..What I learned is that Unity doesnt work well outside of Unity.. not sure I'd recommend doing this

Comment: @Cutetare - Hello, there. That's exactly how i am doing it at this moment. But i'd like to delay startUnity method as it takes up a lot of memory when it starts on app start up. Thanks for replying, though.

Comment: Hi default camera view is opened. are you able to start camera view on button click of storyboard?

Comment: Hi Nisha, yes, that should be possible. If you are using Storyboard, just start the camera per Swift/ObjC, instead of per Unity, take the picture, and then send it to Unity..