# How to embed unity ios project with another ios project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I made a unity project and convert this into iOS project, this create many files which are readable for xcode, now i want to embedd this into another ios project. I am facing difficulty that how can i hookup this (unity converted iOS project) with my specific ios project. Unity converted ios project have `AppController.m` class which is i think First class where every code begin which i equalent to `AppDelegate` in Ios but this is very messy class and couldn't understand how to hookup this with my project. I want whole code and whole functionality of this Unity converted iOS project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093792/xcode-workspace-with-unity3d-as-a-sub-project

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question it may give you some ideas in the right direction.

[Xcode workspace with Unity3D as a sub-project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093792/xcode-workspace-with-unity3d-as-a-sub-project)