# iOS: Communication between Game module (within an app) and rest of the app

Tags: ios, sqlite, unity-game-engine

My team is working on an iPad app that includes a gaming module (could be 2D or 3D).
 We intend to develop the gaming module using one of the Game Engines and are currently evaluating

1. Unity3D
2. iTorque2d
3. and OpenGLES.

Now this gaming module will be interacting with other parts of the app (the way we see it is that there will be a common SQLite database accessible to both the gaming module and rest of the app). 
However, from our initial evaluation it seems that most gaming engines either do now allow this or it is quite tricky to handle it.
Can someone share their experience in case they have tried something similar?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093792/xcode-workspace-with-unity3d-as-a-sub-project/13175771#13175771

Answer (score 0):

We have been working in a very complex system with graphics, html (don't ask, not my doing), and with normal UI.  Our biggest issues were:

- Dealing with context issues in the database--making sure objects were being accessed from the proper context.
- Handling the slow loading bloated size of the tubby Unity engine.  Its so big, that you hate having it in there if you don't need it, but so big that you don't want to have to reload it when switching back and forth with it.