# Unity3D on UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, unity-game-engine

I've have some HTML content that includes unity3d embedded scenes. On a Mac, browsers as Firefos or Chrome can play it using the unity3d plugin, but I can't deal with it on a UIWebView based project. Is there any plugin to show Unity3D embedded scenes on iOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11093792/956886

Answer (score 1):

There is UIWebview overlay for Unity3d on the iPhone. This post explains a way to open up a UIWebView overtop of unity game engine.
here is the link:
http://benbritten.com/2009/09/24/uiwebview-overlay-for-unity3d-on-the-iphone/

Comment: Both links describes how to modify a created unity app to subclass the AppController form unity. But, it's is possible to make and App which can download from a server a .unity3D file and show in a UIView?

Comment: Will not work this way because Unity does not have a web player for mobile browsers.

Comment: @eselk Unity does not have one out of the box, but they do exist.  See my post herein.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple way look at Etcetera plugin by Prime31
You can call WebView from Unity with a single line 
https://prime31.com/docs#iosEtc

look at these

```
// Shows the inline web view. Remember, iOS uses points not pixels for positioning and layout!
public static void inlineWebViewShow( int x, int y, int width, int height )

// Closes the inline web view
public static void inlineWebViewClose()

// Sets the current url for the inline web view
public static void inlineWebViewSetUrl( string url )

// Sets the current frame for the inline web view
public static void inlineWebViewSetFrame( int x, int y, int width, int height )
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UniWebView on the Unity3D asset store.  I have been using this for a few years and it works well, but it may not work for your project.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/uniwebview-3-92605

Disclaimer: This is not my asset and I do not have any connections to the authors.

Comment: HI @Topher, can we resize the top bar which is there in UniWebVIew? I have to add a top bar which Uniwebview has but i couldn't place its position and size.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question makes confusion.

If you want to add HTML view to your game, you can use or embeed chrome in unity, you can use chromium or cefglue to embeed chrome to unity.

but.

If you want to run unity game on UIWebView on android or ios, maybe you should try to first try play your game on existing browser like chrome, if it works, then you can implement your own UIWebView Embeeded Application, that open url to your game. And you should use Chromium Engine i guess, not built in WebView.

Unity Web Player is deprecated, which version of unity do you used?
You should switch to WebGL Platform instead, which doesn't require webplayer plugin.